# PHP preg_replace in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to use preg_replace in a foreach loop.

I need to replace all keywords wrapped between '%' and use the back reference.

For example, in my text I have few keywords like %author% %title%
I need to replace the keywords so they look like $items->author and $items->title

I have tried with the following code but it just displays $items->author as a text and not retrieving the info from the array.

```
      foreach ($xml->book as $items) {
           echo preg_replace('/\%(.*?)\%/e', '$items->${1}', $content);
      }
```

Any idea for this ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$items->{$1}` ?

Comment: You can try with `echo preg_replace('/\%(.*?)\%/e', $items->${1}, $content);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [preg_replace_callback](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this. You cannot just put code as the second parameter in the [preg_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

Like this:

```
<?php

    foreach ($xml->book as $items) {
        echo preg_replace_callback('/\%(.*?)\%/e', function ($matches) use ($items) {
            return $items->{$matches[1]};
        }, $content);
    }
```

Also, it would be best to check if a match was found and if the `$items` array contains a key with this name.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this as the solution to your question if this solved your problem. :)